# How to compute statistical significance using a likelihood ratio?

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, likelihood, constraint

The title really says it all. Suppose I have a change in log-likelihood (i.e., $\Delta LL = LL_{fitted} - LL_{null}$), and I would like to compute the $1\sigma$, $2\sigma$, etc. confidence region from there. How would I do this?

I am looking for the 68%, 95%, 99%, etc. regions of confidence over my parameter space (a 2-parameter model). I am essentially looking for a "level" at which to slice my posterior surface to represent these regions of 68, 95, and 99% confidence.

Comment: The `-2*delta_log_likelihood` has a chi-square distribution with degrees of freedom (n-3).  Compute appropriate quantiles from this distribution.

Comment: The distribution is *approximately* chi-square.